# Find Exchange Manager of different user through VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

How do I look up an Exchange user's manager using their Alias in VBA?

I found VBA code that will pull my manager up.

```vb
Sub GetManager()
MsgBox CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Manager
End Sub
```

I need to put in a user's Alias (like their LDAP) so I can send their manager an email.

Answer (score 0):

The [NameSpace.CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method creates a `Recipient` object. This method is used to verify a given name against an address book. Call the [Recipient.Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method which attempts to resolve a `Recipient` object against the Address Book. For example, you may try to use the following code:

```
Dim myDelegate as Outlook.Recipient
Set myDelegate = OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI").CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") ' try to use your alias here
 myDelegate.Resolve 
 If myDelegate.Resolved Then 
  MsgBox myDelegate.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.Manager
 End If
```

You may find the [ExchangeUser.Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.alias) property which returns a string representing the alias for the `ExchangeUser`.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for your input and quick response.  I inputted the code into VBA and changed the Alias but it gives me a Run-time error '424' "Object required".  I tried to set a Dim as "Dim myDelegate as String" or "Dim myDelegate as Object" but it still gave the same error.

Comment: The Alias property is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

If your code returned a manager then replace `CurrentUser` with user from `CreateRecipient`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub otherUserManager()

Dim user As Object
Dim userAE As AddressEntry
Dim exUser As ExchangeUser

Dim userAlias As String

userAlias = "user1"
Set user = Session.CreateRecipient(userAlias)
Debug.Print user

Set userAE = user.AddressEntry
Debug.Print userAE.Type

If userAE.Type = "EX" Then

    Set exUser = userAE.GetExchangeUser()
    Debug.Print exUser
    Debug.Print exUser.Alias
    
    ' Not tested. Error on both. No manager data on my machine.
    
    ' 1 Assumed valid as indicated in question post
    Debug.Print exUser.Manager  '? Not shown in intellisense
    
    ' 2 GetExchangeUserManager
    Debug.Print exUser.GetExchangeUserManager
    
End If

End Sub
```